Are there any Chazalic sources against learning Torah with dirty hands?
It's brought down in the Poskim that if you touch an uncovered part of your body you shouldn't learn Torah until you clean your hands.
I see that you have to wash your hands before krias shema and tefilla, but is there a source in Chazal from which it may be learned that one must wash their hands before learning Torah?
The earliest source for this seems to be from Rav Yitschak Hachasid in the Kol Bo (siman 11), is this agreed upon among other Rishonim?

See Brachos 11b regarding Rav

@User123 i see, though it could be to get rid of ruach ra, and also after his shiur he said krias shema (14b) which needs nitila

See this answer regarding the need to wash hands in certain circumstances

The Shulchan Aruch (4: 18) records a list of activities that require
one to wash his hands.
אֵלּוּ דְּבָרִים צָרִיךְ נְטִילָה בְּמַיִם...וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ
בְּרַגְלָיו...וְהַחוֹפֵף רֹאשׁוֹ...וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ בְּגוּפוֹ בְּיָדו
"These things require washing with water...one who touches his feet,
one who rubs his head, one who touches his body with his hand."

The Mishna Berurah at 1:2 and 1:8 (bolded phrases) refers to the need to wash hands before learning Torah citing כדין התלמוד והפוסקים (the Talmud and Poskim).
1:2

(ב) השחר – בשל"ה כתב סוד, לחבר יום ולילה בתורה או בתפילה, הן בבוקר הן
בערב. ומיד כשיתעורר משנתו ואינו רוצה לישן, יטול ידיו, אף שנשאר מושכב.
ומכל שכן שלא ילך ארבע אמות בלי נטילת ידים. וצריך מאד ליזהר בזה. ובזוהר
הקדוש מפליג עבור זה בעונשו למאד, כי הוא משהה על עצמו רוח הטומאה. ומכל
מקום, חלילה לעבור שום איסור עבור חסרון נטילת ידיים, כגון לעצור עצמו
מלהשתין על ידי זה, או ליקח מים שהכין חבירו עבור עצמו, אם לא שברור לו
שיתן תיכף תמורתם אחרים. ויש שנכשלין בזה. אם אירע שהמים רחוקים ואין לו
מי שיקרבם אליו, נהגו קצת מבעלי הנפש שהולכים פחות פחות מארבע אמות. וכתב
השערי תשובה על זה דלא נהירא, דעדיף יותר שילכו במרוצה, שלא להשהות רוח
רעה על ידיו. יש אומרים דלעניין זה אמרינן כולא ביתא כארבע אמות דמי, אבל
אין לסמוך על זה כי אם בשעת הדחק. אם אירע כשמשכים בלילה שאין לו מים
ליטול ידיו שלוש פעמים כראוי להעביר רוח הטומאה, אף על פי כן חלילה לו
לבטל מדברי תורה משום זה עד שיאיר היום, אלא יטול מעט או ינקה ידיו בכל
מידי דמנקי ויברך וילמוד, כדין התלמוד והפוסקים

Translation of bolded wording in 1:2 (above) and 1:8 (below) copied from Sefaria

If, when one arises at night, he sees that he does not have enough
water to wash his hands three times properly to rid the spirit of
impurity -  nevertheless, he should not God forbid forgo his Torah
study because of this until daylight, but rather he should wash his
hands a little or clean his hands on whatever he has to wash, make a
blessing, and learn, as per the law of the Talmud and the Poskim
[commonly referring to Rabbinic discussions post-Talmud, particularly
contemporary halachic discussions].

1:8

(ח) בזריזות – לאו דווקא, אלא ישהה מעט ולא יעמוד פתאום, כי זה מזיק לגוף
[גיטין דף ע']. טוב לומר תיכף בקומו: "מודה אני לפניך מלך חי וקיים
שהחזרת בי נשמתי בחמלה, רבה אמונתך". ותיבת "בחמלה" יהיה באתנחתא, ו"רבה
אמונתך" בלי הפסק. והוא מן הכתוב: "חדשים לבקרים" וגו', שהקב"ה מקיים
אמונתו להחזיר נשמות המופקדים בבוקר. ואין צריך לזה נטילת ידיים, ואף אם
ידיו מטונפות, כי אין מזכיר בזה הנוסח לא שם ולא כינוי. ומכל מקום ללמוד
נראה דאסור קודם שנטל ידיו, ובלאו הכי אסור קודם ברכת התורה. ועיין לעיל
סוף ס"ק ב'. סעיף ג [עריכה]


Nevertheless, it seems it is forbidden to learn Torah before washing
hands, and even without that, it is forbidden [to learn] before
[reciting] the blessing of the Torah.  See further above at the end of
se'if katan 2.

There is a talmudic source at
Bava Kamma 17a
אמר רבה בר בר חנה הוה אזילנא בהדיה דר' יוחנן למשאל שמעתא כי הוה עייל לבית הכסא והוה בעינא מיניה מלתא לא פשיט לן עד דמשי ידיה ומנח תפילין ומברך והדר אמר לן אפילו קיים אמרינן לימד לא אמרינן
Rabba bar bar Ḥana said: I was once walking together with Rabbi Yoḥanan to ask him about this statement. Whenever he would enter a lavatory, upon his exit I would ask him to explain a matter, and he would not answer us until he had washed his hands and donned his phylacteries and made the blessing, and only then would he answer us.

The question asks 1)  "where in chazal do we see one needs to wash hands before learning torah" 2) "is this agreed upon amongst the other reishonim?" .... how does this answer those questions?

@Deuteronomy the MB cites כדין התלמוד והפוסקים .

@EdwardB i even cited an earlier source to wash before learning. Im asking where in chazal do we find such an issur or chiyuv.

I have added a reference to Bava Kamma 17a @Deuteronomy

For bracha you also need to wash because you mention hashems name.

When the MB cites כדין התלמוד והפוסקים he is referring to the need to wash before saying blessings, not necessarily to a need to wash before learning (such as for example after touching your feet in the middle of the day). As for BK17a what source do you have (ideally a Rishon) that learns a requirement to wash before learning Torah from there? It could just as well be argued that he held that one must wash before saying asher yasar and that one ought not discuss anything else, even Torah matters, if there is a standing obligation to bless.

@Shlomy just as a sidenote, the Rambam doesn't hold you need to wash in order to bless/say H's name (for example, the first thing said upon arising is אלוקי).  There's a decent essay on the larger topic here.

@Deuteronomy it seems from the Rosh like that as well.

Also chida brings that zohar says person who goes to bathroom has ruach ra and cant learn untill he gets rid of it.
